# How to get the index of the row (cell) I clicked on in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am beginner in Swift and probably this is fundamental stuff but I need to get the index of the row (cell) I clicked on in the tableview.

I have TableViewController with predefined methods, but I wasn't able to find what I am looking for.

Rows (cells) are string from the string array.

Comment: Please review the documentation for UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: Or look at the several duplicates on this very site.Prefer documentation though.

Comment: If you have a solution, do post it as an answer. Do not add it to your question. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer you should accept one of the other answers that told you how to do this.

Comment: @rmaddy you should be more observant. He edited his answer from the point "Specifically" after I posted my solution which I got from the comments where one guy told me to connect two things together. He is just hunting reputation and his goal was to be checked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Implement table view delegate then you can detect your index cell by using method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview

Specifically:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("your row number: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just want to get the index in Int form. Any ideas?

Comment: indexPath.row The value of the row element of the index path.
in case your table has one section only then you can miss indexPath.section and don't take it in account

Comment: @MapeSVK: I updated my answer. You can get your Int index by using indexPath.row. Hope this helps.

Comment: @qtngo Yes, I already have it. I posted the answer. Anyway, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your TableView contains TableViewCells. All the logic when you touch a cell can be programmed in

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

**Update**
`indexPath.row` will get you the index of the chosen tableviewcell

Comment: I need to get the index in Int form. Can you tell me, how? You didn't provide answer, just don't hunt reputation

Comment: Sorry, read over the actual question, updated the answer. Better?

Comment: No, I am getting all the indexes in the table, not the one I clicked on

Comment: @Ricardo the method you mentioned in your answer has nothing to do with taping/selectibg a cell. It is called so that you can provide a cell to be drawn on screen.

Comment: @Losiowaty Could you, please, provide me some tip, or name of the method I can use to achieve my goal? Thank you

Comment: The other answer provided by @qtngo is correct (along with Dmitry A. comment as to how to get the actual index/row).

Comment: I'm so sorry, your totally right @Losiowaty I'll update my answer!

Comment: @Losiowaty thank you so much, finally somebody who could tell me